# Issue with parameters after converting to bytes32

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

> In the contract I have a function, which parses bytes32 array,
>   dependence of exchange type, there are can be different parameters

When I try to call this function with Remix all works well

When I try through web3js on frontend side I get this error for the same parameters

```
invalid bytes32 value (arg="_additionalArgs", coderType="bytes32", value=[31,87,61,111,179,241,61,104,159,248,68,180,206,55,121,77,121,167,255,28]
```

[31,87,61,111,179,241,61,104,159,248,68,180,206,55,121,77,121,167,255,28] this is address in bytes32

I use this for convert address to bytes32

`web3.utils.padLeft(web3.utils.hexToBytes(address, 32))`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
'0x' + web3.utils.padLeft(address.replace('0x', ''), 64);
```

(If `address` doesn't have a leading "0x", you can drop the `.replace(...)`.)

Your current command is passing an extra parameter (`32`) to `hexToBytes` and then calling `padLeft` on a byte array and not supplying a length. A hexadecimal string is the right format already... you just need to pad it to to be 32 bytes (64 hex characters) wide and take care with the `0x` prefix.